# file_get_contents works on localhost but times out on server

Tags: php, timeout, file-get-contents

I have this code :

```
$feed = 'urltorss';
$feeds =  new SimpleXmlElement( file_get_contents($feed) );


$feed = 'http://www.businessweek.com/feeds/homepage.rss';
$feeds =  new SimpleXmlElement( file_get_contents($feed) );
```

Now **both** urls don't have any special characters that require url encoding them, but the 2nd url has an `.rss` extension if it's related.

The first call works and i get a timeout on the 2nd when i try on my server but works perfectly on localhost.

This is the error i'm getting :

```
    Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents('http://www.businessweek.com/feeds/homepage.rss')
[function.file-get-contents]: 
failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Filename: controllers/mailsystem.php

Line Number: 36
```

Why is that?

Comment: Most likely due to your PHP-settings. Try setting script timeout to a higher value.

Comment: the timeout is a solid timeout and in localhost it gets loaded very quickly, and how come this could be settings if the first one works?

Comment: What exactly times out? Your script or the request?

Comment: can you add the url? you can change the domain name or file name in the url.

Comment: First file is in your server and the second one is out side your server right?

Comment: Do you use any proxy server in your network ?
I have tested the url from my browser, i have no problem.

Comment: no both files are external and @Anas i don't really know im on a shared host...

Comment: Can you add the first url "urltorss"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your path so
`echo $feed; // just for debug`
then check the content
`$content = @file_get_contents($feed);`
and in the end, get the XML
`if( $content ) { $feeds =  new SimpleXmlElement( file_get_contents($feed) ); }`

Edit: file_get_contents for URLs will only work if you have allow_url_fopen = 1. To get the content of http://www.businessweek.com/feeds/homepage.rss you need a cURL function that gets the content. Something like http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download

Comment: this is unrelated to the question, i don't wanna check if error happens it's not supoused to happen.

Comment: It's not unrelated... it's about making debug. About "I don't wanna check if error happens"... are you a programmer? :) Because this is all about knowing what's the problem. Anyway... file_get_contents for URLs will only work if you have allow_url_fopen = 1. To get the content of http://www.businessweek.com/feeds/homepage.rss you need a cURL function that gets the content. Something like http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download

Comment: i meant at this point i don't wanna do that... well the problem got solved by itself i guess it was a temporary thing...